# R. How to count row numbers by condition and put into new column

Tags: r

I have been scratching my head trying to solve what seems a simple problem in R. Given the data set called 'DATA' below I want to count the number of incidents of the DATA$ID column and then put those into a new column. So for example the first entry of the new DATA$NEW would be 19 because the ID occurs 19 times. I can't seem to unravel how to do this.

```
PRAY NOTES        ID DURATION
    1    NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    2    NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    3    NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    4    NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    5    NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    6    NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    7    NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    8    NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    9    NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    10   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    11   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    12   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    13   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    14   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    15   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    16   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    17   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    18   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    19   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60
    20    2  <NA> 1_MENS_14       61
    21    3  <NA> 1_MENS_14       61
    22    2  <NA> 1_MENS_14       61
    23    1  <NA> 1_MENS_14       61
    24    1  <NA> 1_MENS_14       61
    25    3  <NA> 1_MENS_14       61
    26    2  <NA> 1_MENS_14       61
    27    3  <NA> 1_MENS_14       61
    28    1  <NA> 1_MENS_14       61
    29    3  <NA> 1_MENS_14       61
    30    3  <NA> 1_MENS_14       61
```

Here's a `dput`:

```
structure(list(PRAY = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), NOTES = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "<NA>", class = "factor"), 
    ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1_MENS_10", "1_MENS_14"), class = "factor"), 
    DURATION = c(60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
    60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 61L, 61L, 
    61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L), NEW = c(19L, 
    19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
    19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L)), .Names = c("PRAY", "NOTES", "ID", 
"DURATION", "NEW"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Apart from the answers below, you can also achieve it without additional packages. Try e.g. something like `df$new <- with(df,ave(rep(1, nrow(df)), id, FUN=length))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DATA)[, NEW := .N, by = ID]

DATA
##    PRAY NOTES        ID DURATION NEW
## 1:   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60  19
## 2:   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60  19
## 3:   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60  19
## 4:   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60  19
## 5:   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60  19
## 6:   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60  19
## 7:   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60  19
....
```

`setDT` converts `data.frame` to `data.table` *by reference* (meaning, no copy of data is being made) and is therefore quite fast. And then,  we *aggregate* by `ID` and add a new column `NEW` containing the counts for *that* group using `.N` an in-built special variable.

> Note: In [v1.9.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table), `setDF` function is now exported, that lets you get back to `data.frame`, once again, *by reference*. So, if you'd like to stick to `data.frame` for some reason, you can just do: `setDF(.)` on the result.

Comment: @Arun,`setDF()` sounds awesome. Was waiting for something like that

Answer (score 2):

`plyr` will do it pretty easily and let you stick with data frames:

```
library(plyr)
dat <- ddply(dat, .(ID), transform, NEW=length(ID))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the `dplyr` equivalent, to complete the set:

```
library(dplyr)

DATA <- DATA %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(ID_Counts = n())

head(DATA)
#Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
#Groups: ID
#
#  PRAY NOTES        ID DURATION NEW ID_Counts
#1   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60  19        19
#2   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60  19        19
#3   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60  19        19
#4   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60  19        19
#5   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60  19        19
#6   NA  <NA> 1_MENS_10       60  19        19
```

Comment: We were waiting for you... :)